# How to check for the same delimiter multiple times?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that contains strings and numbers. All the strings I am searching for have an underscore ("_"), which is my delimiter. However, some strings have the delimiter more than once.
For example:

```
text_in_00
text_in_01
text_out_00
text_out_01
```

Other strings with just one delimiter work beautifully. But here, with two delimiters, "in" and "out" are not being differentiated, due to the delimiter only being found once. How do I find EACH delimiter in a given string?

My goal with this code is to differentiate between ranges and copy and paste these different ranges into their own individual worksheets. Also, I cannot hard-code any cells or strings, as the string names are subject to change, as well as the size of the ranges.

My code:

```
'Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim delimiterItem As String 'was variant
Dim a As Range
delimiterItem = "_"
Set filterRange = FindAll(Worksheets(newSheetName).UsedRange)
For i = filterRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        'arr = Split(Cells(i, 1), delimiterItem)
        'For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
         If Split(filterRange.Cells(i, 1).Text, delimiterItem)(0) <> Split(filterRange.Cells(i - 1, 1).Text, delimiterItem)(0) Then
                Range(filterRange.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow, filterRange.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow).Insert
         End If
     'Next j
Next i
```

Note: FindAll is another function in my code that finds the values I need to be looking at. Some strings don't contain any underscores ("_"), which are values I don't need. This function just filters out what I don't need and works great. I am focusing on the portion of code below the line: `Set filterRange = FindAll(Worksheets(newSheetName).UsedRange))`

Note: The commented out code was something I was trying, but gave the same result.

TLDR; How do I check for each instance of the delimiter? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: What should the expected output be, and what is the output right now?

Comment: You could check the size of the array generated by `Split` to see how many delimiters there are.

Comment: Expected output should be able to differentiate that the two examples I gave are different in regards to "text_in_" and "text_out_". These should go to two different sheets, but they are both going to the same sheet, because it's only finding the first delimiter.

Comment: What do you mean by "go to a different sheet"? Right now you are just inserting rows.

Comment: `InStrRev` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instrrev-function to find the last underscore (if there is one) then check the string to the left of that position

Comment: Code following this copies and pastes the ranges to a different sheet.

Comment: If `filterRange` is not a contiguous range (if it has multiple areas) then you cannot loop over it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to get a count of how many times Char appears in your string and then use a select case construct do do whatever, based on the count.

```
Public Function CountChars(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Char As String) As Long

    CountChars = Len(Source) - Len(Replace(Source, Char, vbNullString))

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that returns the Nth index of a substring inside another:

```
Public Function NthIndexOf(ByVal needle As String, ByVal haystack As String, ByVal n As Long) As Long
    Dim currentN As Long
    Dim currentIndex As Long
    Do
        currentIndex = InStr(currentIndex + 1, haystack, needle, vbTextCompare)
        currentN = currentN + 1
    Loop Until currentIndex = Len(haystack) Or currentN = n Or currentIndex = 0
    NthIndexOf = currentIndex
End Function
```

Now you can get the `NthIndexOf("_", "text_in_00", 2)` and get `8`. If you tried to get the 3rd index of `"_"`, the output would be `0`.

If you want the substring between *each* "delimiter", then you need to `Split` *and then iterate the array*. It's unclear what you intend to do with each substring though, but you should have all the tools you need to do whatever it is that you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiterItem = "_"
    Set filterRange = FindAll(Worksheets(newSheetName).UsedRange)

    For i = filterRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
            If Split(InStrRev(filterRange.Cells(i, 1).Text, delimiterItem))(0) <> Split(InStrRev(filterRange.Cells(i - 1, 1).Text, delimiterItem))(0) Then
                Range(filterRange.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow, filterRange.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow).Insert
            End If
    Next i
```